# How to get a Java Object from JNI call (C++)?

Tags: java, android, object, java-native-interface

I've been researching a bit on how to make JNI calls from C++ to Java, and so far I haven't had any issue, I managed to call almost any type of function. 
I say ALMOST, because right now I'm facing this situation:

In Java, I have this function:

```
public static Object getJObject(int id){
    Object st = null;
    switch (id){
        case 0: st = "hello"; break;
        case 1: st = "bye"; break;
        case 2: st = 1; break;
        case 3: st = 2; break;
        case 4: st = 3; break;
    }
    return st;
}
```

As you can see, this function returns a different type of value given the ID received as a parameter.

The problem comes when trying to get that object from C++. Here's the function that makes the JNI call:

```
bool check(){
    JniMethodInfo methodInfo;
    jobject jobj;

    bool b = getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "org.example.act.activity", "getJObject", "()Ljava/lang/Object;");

    if (!b){
        CCLog("getJObject method not found");
        return false;
    }else{
        jobj = methodInfo.env->CallStaticObjectMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID, 0);
        return true;
    }
}
```

> NOTE: (Although I think it is obvious) note that the
>   *getStaticMethodInfo* method sets the whole process of identifying a method in a Java class. It works with every other function that I
>   call, except for this one.

That's the only thing that I want to do...I'm pretty sure it's something about the signature specifying the type of method it is, but maybe I'm wrong.
So far I've found answered questions about getting a class object or strings, but I haven't found anything on a proper Java Object...

Comment: How does it fail? An Object instance *is* a class instance. Although I would seriously suggest you write some Java wrapper around that method that returns the most specific class possible. Returning just an Object instance is code smell anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature that you are providing to `getStatiticMethodInfo` does not match the method.  For a method that takes an `int` argument and returns an `Object`, the signature should be: `(I)Ljava/lang/Object;`

IIRC, the method signature syntax is described in a couple of places including:

- the JNI specification, and
- the JVM specification

Comment: AW man, I can't believe I missed that little mistake... It's always how it goes hahaha!
Well, it's solved now, although as it turns out, the conversion of tha jobject in C++ gets disastrous results :/
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Double check that you have the package and class name correct, and that the signature agrees with the output of javap -s.

But it's a terrible design.

Comment: Yeah, after editing that tiny mistake (from the answer I chose as correct), the jobject conversion results showed anything but actual values :/
Thanks for replying though!